# MPI C how to access struct/variables of other rank

Tags: c, mpi

So if i have a C code running with MPI and a struct like that:

```
typedef struct Node{
    int succ;
    int pred;
    int has_token;
    char state;
}node;
```

can a rank access another rank node?
For example i have:

```
//What i want:
if(rank==0){
    //so rank 0.state               lets say i want rank 2.state
    if(currentRankNode.state=='I' && someOtherRankNode.state=='S'){
        //do_smth
    }
}
```

And the question is, what should i replace `someOtherRankNode` with to get for example rank 2's node and afterwards the state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, at least you need one communication routine like `MPI_Send`, `MPI_BCast`, `MPI_AllGather` in order to send `someOtherRankNode.state` to `rank == 0`. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(void)
{
    char rank_0_state;
    char rank_1_state;

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    int world_size;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    if (world_size != 2)
        return 1;

    int rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    if (rank == 0)
        rank_0_state = 'I';

    if (rank == 1)
        rank_1_state = 'S';


    if (rank == 0) {
        MPI_Status status;
        MPI_Recv(&rank_1_state, 1, MPI_BYTE, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    }
    if (rank == 1)
        MPI_Send(&rank_1_state, 1, MPI_BYTE, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank == 0) {
        if (rank_0_state == 'I' && rank_1_state == 'S') {
            printf("I am rank 0 receiving the right value from rank 1\n");
        }
    }

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Try to use [MPI_Type_struct](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1/www3/MPI_Type_struct.html) for sending that structure properly across processes.

Comment: Oh yes i did not know about MPI_Type_struct this is actually EXACTLY what i wanted. Very insightful. I should mention MPI_Type_struct is deprecated therefore use MPI_Type_create_struct.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right that function is from the old standard !

Answer (score 0):

With what little information you avail here, I think what you're asking is how to peek into the memory of another MPI process (i.e. to look at the current state of the process with `rank == 2`).

By default the memory spaces of MPI processes are completely separated by the operating system, even if running on the same physical machine. You'll have to synchronize state knowledge by the means of sending and receiving messages. In newer versions of MPI you can use features like MPI Windows: https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.2/www3/MPI_Win_allocate_shared.html, although this is somewhat more complicated.

Comment: I'm a lot out of date with MPI; I understood in the old days that it wasn't really intended as an intra-process communications means, and was primarily intended for inter-machine message passing (back in the days when machines were single core...). I apologise for being lazy in asking, but is that situation changing, that use of MPI withing a single process is becoming more normal? I ask, as I've never liked the idea of having to mix MPI (for inter-machine comms) with OpenMP (for in-machine parallelism). Thank you!

Comment: MPI is designed for _inter_-process communications, i.e. communication between processes with separate memory spaces that may or may not reside on the same physical machine. For _intra_-process communications (i.e. multithreaded, shared-memory applications) we have popular alternatives such as OpenMP, TBB, etc. Mixing the two paradigms can be very efficient.

Comment: Thanks for that Søren. I've often been in the situation where the division of processing within a machine and between machines wasn't clear cut or stable (immature algorithms requiring more development). I've often been tempted by ZMQ; it may involve more copying / overhead than OpenMP, but the ease with which one can relocate a thread from one machine to another (for example, the algorithm matures a bit and chunks of it now use up more processing power than is available in one machine) without a complicated code re-write is useful. ZMQ gives a single paradigm for inter and intra machine.

Comment: I just want to clarify that the two paradigms I'm talking about are shared memory vs. non-shared/distributed memory. ZMQ falls into the second one together with MPI.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I'm drawn to ZMQ because it's close to being both, but with no coding differences inter and intra machine. I'm happy to trade the overhead of zero copy ZMQ on an `inproc` transport and the agility one gets in re-deploying a software architecture across a load of machines, against the performance gained by mixing OpenMP / MPI and the difficulty of redeploying parallel bits of code when forced to because the algorithm guys have made a change. Basically, faster coding vs faster execution.

Comment: Plus these days, with internal DMA, QPI, Hypertransport, etc, I'm not so sure that sharing memory is much different to copying memory, at the microelectronic level. For example, accessing shared memory might involve a QPI transaction. Copying the same memory invovles a very similar QPI transaction (arguably less overall because I'm then not having to maintain cache coherency system wide). Er, does my preference for NUMA architectures look too embarassing?! Thanks again

Comment: As a matter of interest, I have (on an OpenVPX) system developed a data sharing / moving library. For intra-node transactions it passed around memory ownership (so no copying, just control over who could access it). For inter-node transactions it would make the necessary (and unavoidable) DMA transfer. The source code was identical for both, so it was very easy to redeploy lumps of code across the system without having to do much hacking. ZMQ might save me the bother of writing that library ever again.